# Use VB.NET WebBrowser Control to update text field

Tags: html, vb.net-2010

I have an HTML form that I would like to fill in automatically. There is one field in particular that I am having trouble with and it has following HTML code:

```
<input type="text" name="add1" size="13" maxlength="12">
```

As you can see it does not have a value attribute that I can manipulate directly so have to resort to something else. I use the following code to get the desired element:

```
Dim element As HtmlElement = WebBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName("add1").Item(0)
```

This works fine but when I try to use `element.InnerText() = "foo"` the OuterHtml updates to include the new text (`value="foo"` to the HTML above) but `element.InnerText` is stll equal to `Nothing` and when the page is shown to the user the text element still has no input. So what do I need to do to get the text input to show in the proper field?

Comment: It's been a long time since I coded in VB.Net, but one way could be using get parameters. You can even use this technique to use the get parameters using javascript:http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html

Comment: I don't think this would work for me. There is nothing in the URL for me to retrieve. This is an unfilled form and I am trying to programmatically fill it.

Comment: As far as I can remember, you can set the url of the webBrowser object. So you just have to append something like "?param1=value1&param2=value2&..." and then parse it using javascript in html page UNLESS 1. You can't change the url of the webbrowser object for whatever reason OR 2. can't modify the html source code

Comment: I am not able to modify the HTML source code. The device which has the HTML is provided by a 3rd party.

Comment: Well, that's a bummer! Sorry, I hope you find a solution.